# What measures can be taken, so that no political party takes undue advantage of rivalry of other 2 parties?

Tags: voting, voting-systems

Suppose that in a country, there are 3 parties, out of which 2 are opposition and 1 ruling.
If people are not really happy with the ruling party and want to replace it, then they have the option to vote for the other 2 parties.
Here the sole motive is to remove the ruling party, but as the number of votes gets divided between 2 parties (opposition), isn't the ruling party being benefitted?

Comment: In a country where [proportional representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_representation#List_of_countries_using_proportional_representation) is implemented in the elections the effect is much, much smaller. I'm partial to such systems, because 1) a two party system is just one step away from a single party system, 2) the need to form coalitions makes for more intellectual campaigns. If the campaign of a party consists largely of slinging mud on the rivals, the others may remember that when the post-election negotiations to form a coalition commence.

Comment: Having said that, there are downsides. Such as 1) the elected members of the parliament may not always cover the province uniformly (geographically), 2) there will often not be a single party government, so the voters need to split the blame between participants of the ruling coalition.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoiler_effect may be of interest.

Answer (score 4):

That entirely depends on the voting system. If you use [ranked voting or approval voting](https://www.opavote.com/methods/overview) rather than first past the post, a party ranked second or more for enough people may end up with a majority.

(Disclaimer: The link above and its subsections is the best primer I'm aware of on the topic. But I should point out in the interest of transparency that I'm working for the company.)